# Apache filehandle issue expected to be mission critical for image uploading

Tags: media, theming, files, 7

I have a fresh install of Drupal Commons (version 6.25), and I am not allowed to upload an image. [See the full description of this so called **image upload issue** here on this site](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25677/no-image-upload-is-possible-is-there-any-workaround-for-this).

new **Update** one a sitenote...

i want to mention  that i - for the purpose of some tests have put two **sites onto the server**

http://schulcenter.net (for sure Version Drupal-Commons 6.25)
http://schulcenter.org - (probably Version Drupal-Commons 6.23)

and they run on the same database ;-)

guess that that can cause the open File handles
what do you think !? Love to hear from you

well i guess that i have to switch off one site. ;-) greetings (end of update)

here the **original-initial-thread starts:**

I have changed some settings regarding the file handling; I set the permissions for sites/default/files, I created a temporary directory and edited the paths accordingly. All of these seem to work, and workarounds did not change the bad habit of the site: The image upload is impossible.

Can we verify the impact of a decreased amount of Apache File handlers on the possibilities and capabilities of file, and image-handles, especially of the option to upload images? Is there any impact?

dman, a very experienced web and Drupal developer, had a closer look at the site and noticed the site status under the 'Reports' tab lists many errors, including the following one:

> opendir(*) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: Too many open files in /home/vhost/WWW/schulcenter.net/includes/file.inc on line 963.

It seems like it could make *anything* on the site break, especially things that work with files, but also anything that reads files.
I have more than 1200 repots of such message about `opendir("profiles/drupal_commons/modules/acquia/acquia_search/apachesolr/drush")`.

I do not have installed any drush.
Besides this thing, I have no clue why we get such a big amount of open file handles the server is faced with.

> The dblog module monitors your website, capturing system events in a
>   log to be reviewed by an authorized individual at a later time. The
>   dblog log is simply a list of recorded events containing usage data,
>   performance data, errors, warnings and operational information. It is
>   vital to check the dblog report on a regular basis as it is often the
>   only way to tell what is going on.
>
> Details
>      Type   php
>     Date    Sunday, 18 March, 2012 - 21:48
>      User   martin
>      Location   http://schulcenter.net/?q=admin/reports/dblog
>      Referrer
>      Message    opendir(profiles/drupal_commons/modules/acquia/acquia_search/apachesolr/drush) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: Too many open files in /home/vhost/WWW/schulcenter.net/includes/file.inc on line 963.
>      Severity   error
>      Hostname   188.99.184.201
>      Operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you find [this comment](http://drupal.org/node/474152#comment-1779744) on drupal.org?

> The problem is a maximum open files limit per users.
>   We had several web servers, and several new Apache2 VirtualHost; Apache2 (www-data) reached the maximum number of open files (1024).
>
> You can check that with `ulimit -a`  or `ulimit -n`. (The default is maximum 1024 open files.)
>
> You can modify it with `ulimit -n 1500`, but it will be lost after reboot.
>
> To make the change permanent, add in /etc/security/limits.conf:
>
> ```
> #<domain> <type> <item> <value>
> #
> www-data soft nofile 1600
> www-data hard nofile 65535
> ```
>
> Of course, restart your web server.

It explains how to set a per-user limit and increase the number of files that can be opened.  If you don't have enough memory in the server, there may not be many options.

Comment: hello thx for he answer!! i will read the comment you point to.  i havent done it yet, -- i come back and report all my findings - greetings **update** ahh yes  know the story of didier - i stumbled upon it months ago. but now i know that this issue do not have toi do only with the installation [ note i got aware of this issue while installing on the weak server... nowadays i prepare on the local machine and afterwards i port over. i thought that this might be a kind of a workaround... but as we see- i do not get rid of the bad circumstances the server has to face,,,,, . i try to do my best!!

Comment: hope your issue was resolved, it can be frustrating when the server acts up like that.

Comment: hello dear arosboro thx alot. Not yet resolved but workin on it.. I've not worked with this problem before and now i contact my sys-admin.

**Option A **- increase the limit to make things work again. Easy
**Option B** - find why that limit is being hit at all - it's not normal. It may be a side-effect from other things running on that server also, any process there shares the pool of file handles.

Comment: one a sitenote...

i want to mention  that i - for the purpose of some tests have put **two sites onto** the server
http://schulcenter.net ( for sure Version Drupal-Commons 6.25)
http://schulcenter.org - (probably Version Drupal-Commons 6.23 )

and they run on the same database ;-)

guess that that can cause the open File handles
what do you think !? Love to hear from you

 we ll i  guess that i have to switch off one site...

besides these considerations - i guess that you are right - and a move to a new server would fix all the issues and make the troubles go a way greetings